# insert file into editor in ckeditor 4

Tags: javascript, file, plugins, insert, ckeditor

I'm trying to create a plugin that allows a user to insert a content of a file located on his computer. The file is supposed to be an html one. I created the corresponding dialog that I placed into the "ckeditor/plugins/upload/dialog" folder:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('uploadDialog', function(editor) {
    return {
        title: editor.lang.common.upload,
        minWidth: 250,
        minHeight: 100,
        contents: [{
            id: 'uploadTab',
            elements: [{
                type: 'file',
                id: 'fileName',
                label: 'Select file from your computer',
            }, {
                type: 'fileButton',
                id: 'fileId',
                label: 'Upload file',
                'for': ['uploadTab', 'fileName'],
            }]
        }],
        onOk: function() {
            var filePath = this.getValueOf('uploadTab', 'fileName');
            console.log(filePath);
        }
    };
});
```

which works not exactly how I expected: only file name gets available, but not its full path. Another problem arises here: I can not access the content of that file, since the file name is incomplete.